# Uncompressing Gzip buffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, zlib, gunzip

I've got a data buffer compressed by the php function gzcompress and I need to uncompress it in js (nodejs).

```
gzcompress(serialize($slot[$i]['advanced_details']),8)
```

I've tried Class: zlib.Gunzip from https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gunzip

But it throws:

```
{ [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Full buffer [here](http://pastebin.com/JnFuK4j7)

My code:

```
nodeZlib.gunzip(rows[0]['Slot'+(i+1)+'AdvancedDetails'], 8, function(error, data) {
                if(!error) {
                    console.log = data.toString();
                } else {
                    console.log('Error unzipping:');
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing formats. Your confusion is aided by the horrible naming of the functions in PHP. PHP's `gzcompress()` produces the zlib format, whereas node.js's `gunzip` is expecting the gzip format. You could use `gzencode()` in PHP instead to generate the gzip format, or you could use node.js's `zlib.inflate` to decompress the zlib format.

Comment: Wow if it's that... gonna check right now and I'll validate the answer if correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Aaaaaand perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to minify a json output from a shell command. It was too long without encoding it.

The solution I arrived to:

```php
$content = ['sample', 'data'];

$data = base64_encode(gzencode(
    json_encode($content, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
    8,
    FORCE_DEFLATE
));

// then send $data to node
```

and retrieve the data in Node:

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');

let data = zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(data.min, 'base64')).toString();
```